# If a spell states to add "spellcasting ability modifier" do I add just the modifier (wis or int) or the full spellcasting ability (wis + proficiency)

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Spiritual Weapon states damage is "1d8 + your spellcasting ability modifier". As a Cleric my "spellcasting ability modifier" is wisdom with +3.

Does this really mean I only get 1d8+3 since it specifies "modifier" instead of just "spellcasting ability" +5?

Comment: related: [Is there a difference between attack rolls and attack bonus for spells?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95236)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### **You're conflating two separate things.**

**Spell attack bonus** is to hit the target, which gives you a bonus of your spellcasting ability modifier (Wisdom in your case) plus proficiency.  That's the "melee spell attack" referred to in the spell's description.

The **damage done** by the spell if it hits is 1d8 plus your ability modifier (Wisdom again).  So yes it's "only" 1d8+3 for you right now.  But remember, *spiritual weapon* uses your bonus action to make an attack/move, meaning you can attack with it and your own attack, or attack with it and cast a spell, or use an item, and so on, and all without requiring concentration to maintain the spell.  It's pretty powerful in that regard.

Comment: Revisiting this question it helped me to remember that melee/ranged weapon attacks do the same thing. You get add `Modifier+Proficiency` to hit and only `Modifier` to damage.

Answer (score 10):

## You only apply the modifier

Spiritual Weapon states the damage as (per PHB p. 278):

> 1d8 + spellcasting ability modifier

The spellcasting ability modifier is simply the ability score modifier for that attack - in this case, Wisdom, at your stated +3.

You can increase the damage dice by casting this at a higher spell slot.

> When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 3rd level or higher, the **damage increases by 1d8 for every two slot levels above the 2nd**.

### This is different than how you determine a successful attack

The use of proficiency bonuses never applies to damage - only to attack rolls.

Determining a successful attack involves rolling a d20 and adding both your ability modifier and proficiency bonus. Rules around this can be found on page 193 of the PHB.